# How to deselect the first PivotItem in Pivot Office UI Fabric React

Tags: office-ui-fabric

How to deselect the first PivotItem. I am displaying A to Z pivot item and currently its always selecting first letter A. Could you please tell me how to deselect the first element? Thanks!

I want to use getStyles property interface. But not sure how to override. any samples would be great. Thanks

getStyles?: IPivotStyles;

Answer (score 0):

If you mean by deselecting first `PivotItem` selecting a specific one you always provide by yourself vs selecting the first one in the list, then there are several props on the `Pivot` allowing you to do that. [Here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/blob/699fa828b66d5507cfb76851cc0947b4bf54e798/packages/office-ui-fabric-react/src/components/Pivot/Pivot.types.ts#L37-L56) you can see all of them listed as props on the component. By default, if none of them are provided you will get the first `PivotItem` selected on render. In [here](https://codepen.io/vitalius1/pen/oJaWEo) you can see a demo of using the `initialSelectedKey` prop.
There is no way to deselect them all as `Pivot` needs to know what to render when it mounts.

As for the `getStyles` usage, I believe you are using Fabric 5 because in Fabric 6 the prop was renamed to `styles` and it can take a style object or a style function that returns a style object. In the same codepen, you can see how I changed the color of the links by passing a style object.